# Struggling with Navigation Controller basics

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, viewcontroller

I've been pulling my hair out trying to get a basic NavigationController working that will allow me to switch back and forth between views easily. I feel like I'm making progress, but I'm clearly missing something critical. I now have my template app pushing views, but only by adding the initWithNibName pointing to the target NIB. Attempting to add any functionality to these secondary views causes the app to crash with a SIGABRT error. I can't imagine this is right.. If I simply have a plain NIB, the switch works fine. The only thing I've added to the secondViewcontroller is a label and a button to populate the label with some garbage text. Yet the instant I hit the switch button to shift push this view i get the SIGABRT. I'd like to be able to put functionality within the different view controllers. I feel like i'm so close, but tis is so aggravating. Can anyone point out where i've gone wrong?

```
#import "mainViewController.h"


@implementation mainViewController

-(void)switchView {
    UIViewController *secondViewController =   [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
    secondViewController.title = @"My First View";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];  
    [secondViewController release];
}

-(void)switchViewTwo {
    UIViewController *thirdViewController =   [[UIViewController alloc]  initWithNibName:@"thirdViewController" bundle:nil];
   thirdViewController.title = @"My second View";
   thirdViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:thirdViewController animated:YES];
   [thirdViewController release];
}
```

Comment: first thing i would do is go through the implementation files, and capitalise the class names, as both the class name and instance variable, are lower case, so the compiler can't tell the difference. e.g. change secondViewController *secondViewController to SecondViewController *secondViewController.

Comment: Please post the entire crash log. I suspect the issue is with the button itself, not the method in your view controller.

Comment: I second that, post the crash log

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
UIViewController *secondViewController =   [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Put this:

```
MySecondViewController *secondViewController =   [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"secondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

My `MySecondViewController`  should be the name of your `UIViewController`, also check that the XIB's name is really called secondViewController. Finally:

- Go to your XIB
- Select the File's Owner file.
- Select the 3rd tab in the inspector.
- Check the name of the class. It should be `MySecondViewController` instead of `UIViewController`.